# When is a subroutine reference in @INC called?

Tags: perl

As the title says, I'm not clear on when such a subroutine will be called.  From the [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) page at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) one can write:

```
push @INC, \&my_sub;
sub my_sub {
   my ($coderef, $filename) = @_; # $coderef is \&my_sub
   ...
}
```

but where does this go exactly?  The required package or the requiring script (or package)?  I've tried both with some sentinel `print` statements but neither worked so clearly there is something I'm not getting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perl calls a subroutine reference in `@INC` when it is traversing `@INC` to look for a module. That is, you'll trigger it when you try to load a module with `use` or `require` and Perl does not find that module in the preceding `@INC` locations.

```
BEGIN {
    push @INC, 
      sub { print "Oops: There was an error looking for $_[1]\n"; () };
    }

eval "use Cat::Burglar";
eval "use Local::NotThere";
require Cat::Burglar;
```

You need to ensure that your subroutine reference is in `@INC` before you try to load the modules. Remember that `use` is a compile time feature and that `require` is a run time feature. As with adding other "regular" `@INC` entries, you probably want to do it in a `BEGIN` block as early as possible in your program.

Comment: Wow, somehow I've read the `require()` docs many times without noticing this feature!

Comment: The sub is suppose to return nothing, not a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusing our subroutine with the subroutines in the standard Perl modules generally it is good to use the `unshift` instead of `push`. So it will first use your subroutine from the `@INC`.

Comment: I think that should read something like "To *prefer* our sub routine with the loading modules the standard perl modules"

Comment: Which array operation you use depends on what you are doing and when you want to the code reference to trigger. unshift puts it at the front of the array, push at the end, and splice will put it in any position you like. It's task-dependent though.