# Trigger a function when importing a module in Python

Tags: python-3.x

In Perl, we have the `@INC` subroutine trigger that allows executing a subroutine when it's loaded through `use` or `require`. [When is a subroutine reference in @INC called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541119/when-is-a-subroutine-reference-in-inc-called)

Is there something similar in Python? For example, if I have a file `test_random.py` which has `import random` statement in it; is it possible for me to insert `functionX()` in `sys.path` so that when Python searches for `random` in sys.path, it'll run `functionX()` before it finds `random`?

Comment: Not when searching, however upon import python will execute any statement in the module, so if you call `functionX()` in your module, python will run it.

Comment: Right, but don't you think that would be overkill? I have more than 50 modules on my plate and if I need to copy-paste the same `functionX()` in all the modules, that would be a lot of duplicate code

Comment: If you put your 50 modules in one package and put your `functionX()` in `__init__.py` inside that package, python will call it only once. Upon first import from the package.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try it out and get back to this thread.