# How can I wrap require and use?

Tags: perl, require

Let's say I want to wrap `require` such that,

```
package MyModule;
use Data::Dumper;
```

Would output either,

```
MyModule -> Data::Dumper
MyModule -> Data/Dumper.pm
```

For all packages and all `requires`/`use` statements. How could I do it?

Comment: It would be `goto &CORE::require` - CORE::GLOBAL:: is for overriding not calling, so you just called your own override. Except that require is not one of the builtins callable from CORE::, as noted in the [CORE docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/CORE).

Comment: s/callable from CORE::/referenceable as a subroutine/

Comment: I think the terminology you're searching for is that you want to instrument `use` and `require`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```perl
BEGIN {
   unshift @INC, sub {
      printf "%s -> %s\n", ( caller() )[0], $_[1];
      return;
   };
}
```

See the paragraph starting with "You can also insert hooks into the import facility" in [`require`'s documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#require).

Comment: Note the use of a list slice instead of needlessly building an array.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot reference the `require` builtin as a subroutine such as for `goto`, but you can call it from [CORE](https://perldoc.perl.org/CORE).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::require = sub {
    printf "%s -> %s\n", [caller()]->[0], $_[0];
    CORE::require $_[0];
  }
};
use Data::Dumper;
```

You may also consider [Devel::TraceUse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::TraceUse) which is similar to the above but more robust and informative, and can easily be invoked from the commandline.

Answer (score 4):

You can look inside [Devel::TraceUse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::TraceUse) to see working code for what you are trying to do. But, changing definitions isn't a good plan because you don't know who else also changed definitions and will wonder why their stuff stops working.

You don't need to (or should) override `require`. Put a code reference in `@INC` and return false at the end so it looks like that failed and Perl will move on to the next thing in `@INC`:

```
#!perl
use v5.10;

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541138/2766176
BEGIN {
unshift @INC, sub {
    my( $package, $file ) = caller(0);
    say "$package -> $_[1]";
    return 0;
    };

}

use Data::Dumper;

say "Hello";
```

This outputs:

```
main -> Data/Dumper.pm
Data::Dumper -> constant.pm
constant -> strict.pm
constant -> warnings/register.pm
warnings::register -> warnings.pm
Data::Dumper -> Carp.pm
Carp -> overloading.pm
Carp -> Exporter.pm
Data::Dumper -> XSLoader.pm
Data::Dumper -> bytes.pm
Hello
```

Comment: Also, you're suppose to return nothing, not something false.

Comment: Ah, you did beat me. That's what I get for leaving my answer in a tab. :( As for the return value, it's not a big deal , but the wording in the docs is "If an empty list, undef, or nothing that matches the first 3 values above is returned, then require looks at the remaining elements of @INC."

Comment: Oh. The latest docs say "The subroutine should return either nothing or else a list of up to four values in the following order:" (Link in my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Weird requirement needs weird solution: Use a source filter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
{   package Wrap::Use;
    use Filter::Simple sub {
        warn $1 while /use (.*?);/sg;                                  # stupid SO: /
    };
}

BEGIN { Wrap::Use->import }

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
```

Comment: Does that work globally (e.g for modules loaded by other modules)?

Comment: The requirements would need to be significantly weirder than this for me to say it needs a source filter :)