# FindBin for perl modules that reside in my script's directory

Tags: perl

I have a script that uses modules that are external to the standard Perl library and would like for some way to use them. I don't have permissions to install them into the Perl lib directory and was wondering if I could just have these external modules reside in my scripts directory.

I have read about using FindBin but it seems to not work. Am I using it correctly?

Right now I want to use 3 modules I want to use (2 being directories). So lets say my script is in Dir1, then my modules will be in a subdirectory of Dir1 called Dir2.

So assuming FindBin finds Dir1, then all I have to do is this?

```
use FindBin '$Bin';
use Dir2 "$Bin/Dir2";
use Dir2::SubDir_ofDir2_1::Module1;
use Dir2::Module2;
use Dir2::Module3;
```

My program seems to run but it doesn't do anything. So I am pretty sure it is not importing the modules correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Consider [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib) instead. From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [How can I use CPAN as a non-root user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to do it would more likely be either:

```
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/Dir2";
use SubDir::Module1;
```

or:

```
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
use Dir2::Subdir::Module;
```

Both would find the files, behavior would then depend on whether the modules declare themselves as inside `package Dir2` or not.

Check out [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin) and [lib](https://metacpan.org/module/lib)'s documentation.