# What does Perl do when two versions of a module are installed?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I don't have root access on a remote box I'm working with, so I'm using a combination of cpanm and local::lib as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980715/1156644) to install CPAN modules to my local directory on the box. Using cpanm, I assume `cpanm Module::To::Update` would install the newest version of the module in my local library.

Apparently, I don't need root access to upgrade my modules with CPAN, as I just tried it, and the upgrade went swimmingly. However, I'm still curious which version of the module Perl will use: the local version, or the default CPAN version? Or will it just use whichever is newer?

If this exists in perldoc or Stack Overflow, I'd appreciate that as well. I tried searching both, but I wasn't able to find it =/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It uses the first one it finds when searching though [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) in order.

Comment: Oh. That's pretty simple. And presumably specifying `use Module Version` would let me pick which one I wanted manually. Thanks.

Comment: @dgempesaw - That presumption would be incorrect. If you need to load a particular module from a particular place, you'll need to hack at `@INC` or `%INC` (There are lots of ways to do that. How to do that would make a good follow up question).

Comment: @dgempesaw, To find the module's version, Perl needs to execute the module. The module can't be un-executed if it's not the right version.

Comment: @mob I see. I guess I need to read the docs regarding that more closely; I understand `@INC` enough to put my preferred directory first.

Comment: @ikegami That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can check it by running this in linux:

`perl -e 'use <module>; print $<module>::VERSION;'`