# How can I use cpanminus without root and internet access

Tags: perl, cpan

How can I use cpanminus without root and without internet access? I am aware of [this question about cpanminus without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user), but the proposed solution requires internet access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Prepare a (mini-)CPAN mirror: [minicpan](http://p3rl.org/minicpan)/[CPAN::Mini::Devel::Recent](http://p3rl.org/CPAN::Mini::Devel::Recent), [How to mirror CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/misc/how-to-mirror.html)
2. Tell `cpanm` to use your fresh offline mirror with [`--mirror`](http://p3rl.org/cpanm#mirror). URIs with the [`file` scheme](http://enwp.org/File_URI_scheme) are accepted.