# How can I install cpanm and local::lib if I can't write to ~/?

Tags: perl, cpan

As with many people whose sites are hosted on shared servers, I do not have root access, and the hosting company will not install Perl modules at the request of users.

Unfortunately, I also do not have write privileges to the `~/` folder, only to certain subfolders (such as `~/cgi-bin/`).

I've attempted the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980715/270404), changing `~/perl5` to `~/cgi-bin/perl5` (which I created), but I keep getting this error:

> "Can't write to cpanm home '~/.cpanm': You should fix it with
>   chown/chmod first."

The problem is, as I stated, **I don't have write privileges to ~/**.

Is there some way to tell the installer to use `~/cgi-bin/.cpanm` instead? I've tried to figure it out by searching on here and elsewhere on the internet, but I'm starting to bash my head against the wall.

**EDIT :** So I've tried the suggestion by Steven below, using this command:

> HOME=$HOME/cgi-bin cpanm local::lib

Now, `cpanm` successfully runs and tries to install the module, but has numerous warnings throughout the installation and ultimately fails (presumably something is still trying to write to a forbidden folder??).

Here are some sample warnings:

> Warning: prerequisite CPAN 1.82 not found. We have 1.7601.
>
> Warning: prerequisite ExtUtils::Install 1.43 not found. We have 1.32.
>
> Warning: prerequisite ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.42 not found. We have 6.17.
>
> Warning: prerequisite Module::Build 0.36 not found.
>
> Warning: You do not have permissions to install into /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 114.
>
> mkdir /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/App: Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 176
>
> make: *** [pure_perl_install] Error 255

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory

Comment: That question is related (though not precisely the same), but I run into the same "permission denied" error for ~/.cpan or ~/.cpanm, even when I specify a different INSTALL_BASE directory.

Comment: How come this question is closed? And even if it is why for `off topic`? How is this question `off topic`? You should explain before clicking on close.

Comment: [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close)
Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. **Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.** Read more about closed questions here.

Comment: How is the question off topic? It is definitely a practical, answerable question about popular software for developers.

Answer (score 1):

`~` is just a shorthand way of accessing the environment variable `$HOME`, so you should be able to do something like `export HOME=$HOME/cgi-bin` to move your effective home directory down into some directory you have write permissions for.  This will affect many things, however, so be careful.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds pretty dangerous to me, I would much rather somehow pass this subdirectory to cpanm via the command line. But it's definitely something to consider as a last resort.

Comment: If you prefix the command with HOME=$HOME/cgi-bin
e.g. HOME=$HOME/cgi-bin cpanm ...
then your home is only reset for that command.