# How to set up separate Perl modules for non-login users?

Tags: perl, cpan

Inspired of [How can I use CPAN as a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user) i'd like to know, how to set up cpanm for non-login users (like `www`)? There is no login, so i don't know how to include some dir to `@INC`.

Edit:
How i could set permanently enviroment var like PERL5LIB for non-login user? I can't set it from `.bashrc` (needs login) and not from `/etc/environment` (sets to everyone).

Comment: Maybe some suggestions here may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables/88229

Comment: @SlavenRezic: Thank you, but those solutions involve log-in or set variables for every user.

Comment: Did you look at the `~/.pam_environment` solution? Note the `~`.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: I did, it says "is read by all login methods that use PAM". Non-system users don't use this file for setting env, as far i understand. For sake I tried it, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Methods of changing `@INC`:

On a per-script basis:

- [`use lib ...;`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib)
- [`-Mlib=...`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) on the shebang line.

On a per-process basis:

- Set the [`PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) env var from the parent process.

  - `sh`: `export PERL5LIB=... ; perl ...`
  - `sh`: `PERL5LIB=... perl ...`
  - `apache`: `SetEnv PERL5LIB ...`

On a per-`perl` basis:

- Specifying the directories for `@INC` when configuring `perl` when building it.
- [`use lib ...;`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib) in a script named `sitecustomize.pl` in the directory returned by `perl -V:sitelib`.<sup>[1]</sup>

Of course, you could also install your own local Perl, perhaps using [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew).

---

Notes:

1. Perl only looks for `sitecustomize.pl` if The `perl` has been configured to do with `-Dusesitecustomize`. Check with `perl -V:usesitecustomize` to see if it was.

Comment: some reference to PERL5ENV?

Comment: Outside of script, how you obtain it for a non-login (system) user?

Comment: Links to docs added. It's a `PATH`-like var, i.e. a colon-separated paths in which to search. (They're added to `@INC`.) Like `use lib` (and unlike `-I`), any arch subdirs will be added as well.

Comment: `PERL5ENV` should be `PERL5LIB` ? How to set it for a non-login user?

Comment: Yes, `PERL5LIB`. A process's environment is always set by the parent process. What's the parent process? Apache? `SetEnv`.

Comment: Which is parent process for `www-data` running different services? Like Apche, nginx, starman, Dancer, cron-scripts. Don't want set them up separately, but can't find solution.

Comment: You've previously said you don't want to set it on per-script basis. Now you're saying you don't want to set it on a per-process basis. That leaves setting it on a per-`perl` basis. (See update)

Comment: No, i want it set **per-user** basis. I want that everything i run under this user uses separate modules. Setting it by parent process sounded as good idea to me, but what is a parent process for all those things i listed above?

Comment: Why are you asking me? How should I know what programs you have running on your machine, and which instances were used to create which other instances?

Comment: I've listed your options.

Comment: Of course, some of the options can be used to limit the effect to a particular user (e.g. `use if $USER eq ..., 'lib', ...;` instead of `use lib ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Make the first `perl` in your $PATH a shell script that checks for a file named after the invoking user, sources that file, and then calls the real perl:

```
    $ cat /usr/local/etc/perl.user.d/www-data
    PERL5LIB=/whatever/you/need
    export PERL5LIB
```

```
    $ cat /usr/local/bin/perl
    #! /bin/sh

    PERLBIN=/usr/bin/perl

    USER_CUSTOMIZE=/usr/local/etc/perl.user.d/$(whoami)

    [ -e "$USER_CUSTOMIZE" ] && source "$USER_CUSTOMIZE"

    exec $PERLBIN "$@"
```

*N.B.*  I don't heartily recommend this.  It's similar to `sitecustomize.pl` [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027057/132382), but more hackish.  Like the others who have answered, I don't think it would be too arduous to identify all of the parent processes you care about (apache, cron, and ... ?) and set PERL5LIB there.