# Failing to start perl program because of missing modules

Tags: perl, cpanm

Okay, so I'm not familiar with perl and all I want is to run a bioinformatic tool from [here](http://www.smallrnagroup.uni-mainz.de/software.html) on a server where I don't have root privileges. But I keep getting errors about missing modules:

```
Perl module Archive::Extract (in core since 2007-07-07) is not installed on this machine!
Perl modules are available for download at http://www.cpan.org/

If you have CPAN installed try the following:
 cpan
 install Archive::Extract
 exit
```

Our system administrator is a huge Richard, so, naturally, I went to search for answers online and it only got worse! I tried to set up PERL5LIB, I found and installed cpanm from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user) answer. Then it worked, but when I tried to install Archive::Extract it said:

```
Archive::Extract is up to date. (0.80)
```

And now I'm about to lose my mind. Please help me before I crash that server with a sledgehammer (just kidding, but any help is much appreciated).

Comment: Not having Archive::Extract installed suggests you are using a really old version of Perl. What does `perl -v` produce?

Comment: @JGNI it's 5.10.1, but I think, using local::lib somehow makes it older or something, I don't know, what's happening :(

Comment: Ok try using perlbrew https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew which lets you install your own version of Perl in your home directory