# What's the search order in perl's include path when a module is loaded

Tags: perl

Let's say there are three paths in `@INC`: `path1`, `path2` and `path3`. Under each of these paths, there is a module named `foo.pm`. If I now load `foo.pm` in my script via `use foo;`, which of the `foo.pm`s is actually going to be loaded? Or in other words, what is perl's search order for paths in `@INC`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I choose a package name for a custom Perl module that does not collide with builtin or CPAN packages names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658955/how-do-i-choose-a-package-name-for-a-custom-perl-module-that-does-not-collide-wi) (That question covers more ground, but it includes this question.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a Perl program know where to find the file containing Perl module it uses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526520/how-does-a-perl-program-know-where-to-find-the-file-containing-perl-module-it-us) . Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe

Answer (score 8):

[perldoc -v %INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC) shows which path was chosen:

```
use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper(\%INC);
```

Or...

```
perl -Mfoo -e 'print $INC{"foo.pm"}'
```

[require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) shows some psuedo-code which implies the search order:

```
foreach $prefix (@INC) {
}
```

Thus, `path1` would be searched first.

Answer (score 6):

path1, path2, path3. And perl will load `path1/foo.pm`.

Why would you expect it to be any other?

Looking at [`perlfunc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC), I can see that they don't *explicitly* say this, but they do say:

> The array @INC contains the list of places that the do EXPR , require, or use constructs look for their library files.

I think the hint on there is *list*. It's unexceptional to expect a *list* to be processed first-to-last.

You could probably put this code, right before your `use foo;` statement:

```
BEGIN { say "\@INC=(${\join( ', ', @INC )})"; }
```

If that still shows you `@INC=(/path1, /path2, /path3)` then put this after the `use` statement:

```
BEGIN { say "\$INC{'foo.pm'}=$INC{'foo.pm'}"; }
```

And if that one still shows `$INC{'foo.pm'}=/path3/foo.pm`, then I think you're not specifying your search paths as well as you might. You might think you have `foo.pm` in the same directory specified as '/path1', but the likelihood is that you've got some path messed up.

Comment: \@Axeman: I print @INC and the printed order is path1, path2 and path3, me too expected that it's path1/foo.pm is loaded, but in my case path3/foo.pm is loaded. there are two possibilities here, one is that the printed order is the reverse of search order, or something crazy...

Comment: @HaiyuanZhang `@INC` should print out in order, again as it is a list. Perhaps you do some manipulation with `@INC` in something that runs after the `BEGIN` blocks (and remember that `use` is an implicit `BEGIN` block). So you can write code like this: `unshift @INC, qw</path1 /path2>;use foo;` and end up with an implementation of `foo` in the path3. Sequential location in the file does not dictate sequential processing, necessarily. See [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)