# Issue with the search order when including perl modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

this question is a follow up to:
[What's the search order in perl's include path when a module is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357477/whats-the-search-order-of-perl-include-path-when-a-module-is-loaded) posted a while back but that remained unanswered.

I have 2 versions (1.22 and 1.25) of the module IO installed in two separate folders:

`/some_path/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/` (for IO.pm version 1.25)
and 
`/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/` (for IO.pm version 1.22)

The @INC list looks like:

```
/some_path/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/  
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/  
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/  
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/  
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/  
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/  
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/  
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/  
.
```

When i try `perl -e 'use IO'`, perl returns the following error message:
IO object version 1.22 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.25 at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 253.
which suggests that the IO module version 1.22 is used instead of IO version 1.25 even though the IO version 1.25 should be located first.

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Remained unanswered?! The linked question has two perfectly fine answers: Perl searches from the lowest index of @INC to the highest until the desired file is found.

Comment: sorry, what I meant is that the answers provided to the questions didn't solve my particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bad install of IO.

`perl` is finding 1.25's `IO.pm` in `/some_path/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/` as intended, but the first `auto/IO/IO.so` it finds is 1.22's (in `/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/`?)

Comment: Thanks! the 1.25's IO.so was indeed missing. Re-installing solved my problem.