# Import Perl module from another directory

Tags: perl, import, module

I have the following file structure:

```
|_controllers
| |___FooController.pm
|_models
| |___Foo.pm
|_utils
| |___BarUtils.pm
|_foobar.do
```

I want to know how can I import the modules between files, let say that I want to use Foo.pm on FooControllers.pm or use BarUtils.pm on foobar.do . When I have the files on the same directories I just do

> use Foo;

But in this case I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that:

- The parent directory (the one that contains `controllers` etc..) is in `@INC`
- The modules would then be named:

  ```
  use controllers::FooController;
  use models::Foo;
  ```

The exact rationale for how and why this works (as well as `@INC` details) can be found on SO:

- [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)
- [How does a Perl program know where to find the file containing Perl module it uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526520/how-does-a-perl-program-know-where-to-find-the-file-containing-perl-module-it-us)

Comment: Thanks, I also found that require './utils/Connection.pm'; works but you'll have to set all the routes manually so it's better to add the path to the %INC